# Questions about user login through REST API

Tags: android, android-intent

My site has a REST API set up. I have a login view on my app and I need to implement user authentication now.

When sending the user credentials to the web server, I'm assuming I should encrypt it first, correct?

When the user is authenticated successfully, how do I keep that user logged in and set their app to contain the user's data (like their user ID, username, etc) so that I can send it to the API when they do some other action in the app?

Any security issues to know about?

Thanks.

Comment: Sessions would imply a notion of "state", but he requested advice to login with a REST Api, which is inherently stateless... Rather than a session he should attempt a login and generate an auth token that would then be passed with every rest api call involving private user data. This doesnt solve the security component of the data in motion through the network though

Comment: @LucasCrawford What, besides using HTTPS, would I need to do security wise?

Comment: If you are using `RoR` and `JSON`, this is useful a [link](https://thesocietea.org/2015/04/building-a-json-api-with-rails-part-3-authentication-strategies/)

Comment: Read the above article, it is exactly what I tried to say in comment space :)